# Unexpected module path "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"

Tags: go

I've used `"github.com/sirupsen/logrus"` and I can't manage to remove it

I've tried

`go mod tidy`

`go clean -modcache`

This is the log:

`go: github.com/Sirupsen/logrus@v1.4.0: parsing go.mod: unexpected module path "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"`

I've even deleted the `mod` directory.

Comment: Have you deleted the line from `go.mod` and made sure it's not being `import`ed anywhere (including transitively by any other dependencies)?

Comment: Yes and it adds it back when I clean the cache.

Comment: If it's adding it back, it's being used by *something*. Try running `go mod why github.com/sirupsen/logrus`.

Comment: I've found the solution on github, thank you. It seems it's a case-sensitive import collision, thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found the solution:

I've replace in `go.mod`

```
replace (
    github.com/Sirupsen/logrus v1.3.0 => github.com/Sirupsen/logrus v1.0.6
    github.com/Sirupsen/logrus v1.4.0 => github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.0.6
    github.com/Sirupsen/logrus v1.0.5 => github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.0.5
)
```

github.com/Sirupsen/logrus/github.com/sirupsen/logrus is a breaking change; because an import path of github.com/Sirupsen/logrus now no longer works when in module mode (the irony). Hence I think the module release of github.com/Sirupsen/logrus/github.com/sirupsen/logrus should in fact have been a v2 release.

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/28489
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26208